# Regularity of the language

Tags: regular-language

$L= \{ xy \mid x,y \in \{a,b\}^* \}$ is not a regular language. But would it make a difference if we added another constraint that $|x|=|y|$. Would this enforce the condition of finiteness on the language?

Comment: Both $\{xy \mid x,y \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ and $\{xy \mid x,y \in \{a,b\}^*, |x|=|y|\}$ are regular languages.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Oh am I wrong in stating that {xy|x,y E {a,b}*} is not regular? Please correct me and give me a reasoning for the same. Also, would it be different from {ww|w E{a,b}*}

Comment: $L=\{xy \mid x,y \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ means exactly the same as $L=\{a,b\}^*$.  Are you sure this is the language you mean?

Comment: Yes of course these are different.  In order to write a string as $ww$ it must be a smaller string exactly repeated.  But every string can be written as $xy$ for some $x$ and $y$.  Can you imagine any string that can't?

Comment: yes I mean to evaluate L= {xy| x,y E {a,b}* and |x|=|y|} . If you mean so say that it equals {a,b}* then it is regular as there can be a DFA to represent it. However, if the length is infinite then it cannot. So does |x|=|y| state that the length is finite. or irrespective of any condition {a,b}* is regular?

Comment: Yes, $|x|=|y|$ implicitly means that the lengths are finite.  But actually, $\{a,b\}^*$ only consists of finite-length strings.  There is no such thing as an infinite string in a language.

Comment: I suppose that by now it's moot, but you've gotten four good answers to this question and you evidently know how to accept an answer, so why not accept one of these? If I were you, I'd pick Brian's, if for no other reason than he's really close to breaking into the 100K reputation club.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you’ve been having some trouble with this material, so I’m going to discuss the two languages that you mention in some detail.

By definition the strings in $\{a,b\}^*$ are all finite; that’s something that you never have to worry about.

Now let’s look at the two languages that you mentioned, $$L_1=\{xy:x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\}$$ and $$L_2=\{xy:x,y\in\{a,b\}^*\text{ and }|x|=|y|\}\;.$$

If $w$ is any word in $\{a,b\}^*$, we can write $w=w\epsilon$, where $w,\epsilon\in\{a,b\}^*$, so $\{a,b\}^*\subseteq L_1$. On the other hand, it’s obvious that $L_1\subseteq\{a,b\}^*$, so $L_1=\{a,b\}^*$. That is, $L_1$ is just the set of all finite strings of $a$’s and $b$’s, including the empty string. This certainly **is** a regular language: it’s recognized by the DFA that has just one state, which is an acceptor state, and transitions from that state to itself for both $a$ and $b$. Alternatively, it’s generated by the regular grammar whose productions are

$$S\to aS\mid bS\mid\epsilon\;.$$

Now $L_2$ is definitely **not** all of $\{a,b\}^*$, because $a\notin L_2$. To see this, note that the only ways to write $a$ in the form $xy$ for $x,y\in\{a,b\}^*$ are with $x=a$ and $y=\epsilon$, or with $x=\epsilon$ and $y=a$. But $|a|=1\ne 0=|\epsilon|$, so neither of these decompositions satisfies the defining condition for members of $L_2$. On the other hand, $aa\in L_2$, because we can write $aa$ as $xy$ with $x=a$ and $y=a$.

What words $w\in\{a,b\}^*$ can be written in the form $xy$ with $|x|=|y|$? If $w=xy$ is such a word, then $|w|=|x|+|y|=2|x|$, so $|w|$ must be an even number. In other words, we now know that every $w\in L_2$ has even length. This automatically rules out words of odd length, like $a$, $bba$, $abbab$. The next question that you should ask is whether anything else is ruled out: are there words of even length that are **not** in $L_2$?

Suppose that $w\in\{a,b\}^*$ and $|w|$ is even; then $|w|=2n$ for some non-negative integer $n$. If $n=0$, then $w=\epsilon$; is this in $L_2$? Yes, because $\epsilon=\epsilon\epsilon$, and $|\epsilon|=|\epsilon|$. Now suppose that $n>0$. Then we can write out the word $w$ as $c_1c_2\dots c_nc_{n+1}\dots c_{2n}$, where each $c_k$ is either $a$ or $b$. Is it possible to write $w$ in the form $xy$, where $x,y\in\{a,b\}^*$ and $|x|=|y|$? Sure: just make $x$ the first $n$ letters of $w$ and $y$ the last $n$ letters. To be precise, let $x=c_1c_2\dots c_n$ and $y=c_{n+1}c_{n+2}\dots c_{2n}$. Therefore $w\in L_2$, and we’ve shown that every $w\in\{a,b\}^*$ of even length belongs to $L_2$.

Putting the pieces together, we see that a word in $\{a,b\}^*$ belongs to $L_2$ if and only if its length is even: $L_2=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*:|w|\text{ is even}\}$. Once you realize this, it’s easy to design a DFA that recognizes $L_2$ or a regular grammar that generates $L_2$. You can do it with a two-state DFA, or with a regular grammar with two non-terminal symbols and five productions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: start by asking yourself which strings can be broken down into $xy$ with $|x|=|y|$ and which ones can't.  For instance, which of the following strings do you think belong to the language $\{xy \mid x,y \in \{a,b\}^*, |x|=|y|\}$?

$b$, $aa$, $ab$, $ababab$, $aaabbbb$?

Once you can see a simpler way to understand this language, it should become very obvious how to build a finite state machine which recognizes it.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Gigili At present the question is ill-posed and the poser appears to have significant misconceptions.  A full answer seemed premature.  Is it generally inappropriate to phrase an answer in hint form?

Comment: It is indeed. But are you claiming the two languages are regular by this example?

Comment: @Gigili: I'm not entirely convinced that this answer should be fleshed out any further, but I see your point about the lack of actual "answer" in the original version.

Answer (score 0):

$L={xy∣x,y∈{a,b}}^∗}$ is the same as $∑^*$ so it has all the strings! and you can find a DFA that accepts all the strings (it has one state, which is both the initial state and the final state)so it is regular.
{xy∣x,y∈{a,b}∗,|x|=|y|} is the same as {w| |w| is even} which is a regular language (you can find a DFA with 2 states for it)

Answer (score 0):

I'll make another stab at clarifying this, unpacking your question.

> $L=\{xy\ |\ x, y \in \{a, b\}^*\}$ is not a regular language.

This is false. This language consists of strings of the form $xy$, where $x\text{ and }y$ can be any finite strings (including the empty string) consisting of $a$s and $b$s. So, because $x$ or $y$ can be the empty string, it simply consists of all strings over $\{a, b\}$, namely the language denoted by the regular expression $(\mathtt{a}+\mathtt{b})^*$, which is of course regular, by definition. Or, if you prefer, there's Brian's answer: a FA for this has one state, which is both the start and final state and has a transition function that on $a$ or $b$ goes to itself.

> Would $L=\{xy\ |\ x, y \in \{a, b\}^*\text{ and } |x|=|y|\}$ be a regular language?

Yup. Since it's made up of the concatenation of any strings over $\{a, b\}$ which are of the same length, this language is just all strings of even length over that alphabet. A FA for it would have two states, a start state (which is also the final state) and another one, with $a, b$ transitions between both. Or, if you'd prefer regular expressions, it's the language denoted by $(\mathtt{aa}+\mathtt{ab}+\mathtt{ba}+\mathtt{bb})^*$.

> (In your comment) Does $|x|=|y|$ state that the length is finite?

Not immediately. But if we back away from this, the definition of $\Sigma^*$ for a set of characters $\Sigma$ is the set of all *finite* strings using characters from $\Sigma$. We use this definition because allowing infinitely long words in a language makes an awful lot of the nice results about languages invalid. In other words, to keep us paying in a friendly sandbox, we require that a *language* is a (possibly infinite) set of *finite* strings over a *finite* alphabet.